# what are the limits to a counter in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on a script and I am adding a counter to it, but I'm not sure how to control it better

I added this to my script - My script is very large about 96 rows so I am trying to only focus on building counters

```
Set A/ Serial=0
and then this
Set A/ serial+=1
```

When I run my tester.txt it counts like it's suppose with the script above

```
New folder 1\tester.txt before - current script
this is the content inside my tester.txt
    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 0,
    "gachaConfig": 0,
    "amount": 0,
```

my tester.txt will literally have the same code repeated from 6 to 18 times

MY RESULTS the amount is not adding corectly

```
    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 1,
    "gachaConfig": 1,
    "amount": 1000, 

    "partType": 1,
    "partGrade": 2,
    "gachaConfig": 2,
    "amount": 5,   ---- should be 1001 also I want to increase by 500
                        or 1500 depends on the code
    "partType": 2,
    "partGrade": 3,
    "gachaConfig": 3,
    "amount": 0,  --- This 0 should not be here

    "partType": 3,
    "partGrade": 4,
    "gachaConfig": 4,
    "amount": 1,

    "partType": 4,
    "partGrade": 5,
    "gachaConfig": 5,
    "amount": 2,

    "partType": 5,
    "partGrade": 0, --- This 0 should not be here
    "gachaConfig": 0, --- This 0 should not be here
    "amount": 3,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 1,
    "gachaConfig": 1,
    "amount": 4,

    "partType": 1,
    "partGrade": 2,
    "gachaConfig": 2,
    "amount": 5,

    "partType": 2,
    "partGrade": 3,
    "gachaConfig": 3,
    "amount": 0, --- This 0 should not be here

    "partType": 3,
    "partGrade": 4,
    "gachaConfig": 4,
    "amount": 1,

    "partType": 4,
    "partGrade": 5,
    "gachaConfig": 5,
    "amount": 2,

    "partType": 5,
    "partGrade": 0, --- This 0 should not be here
    "gachaConfig": 0, --- This 0 should not be here
    "amount": 3,

    "partType": 0,
    "partGrade": 1,
    "gachaConfig": 1,
    "amount": 4,

    "partType": 1,
    "partGrade": 2,
    "gachaConfig": 2,
    "amount": 5,

    "partType": 2,
    "partGrade": 3,
    "gachaConfig": 3,
    "amount": 0, --- This 0 should not be here

    "partType": 3,
    "partGrade": 4,
    "gachaConfig": 4,
    "amount": 1,

    "partType": 4,
    "partGrade": 5,
    "gachaConfig": 5,
    "amount": 2,

    "partType": 5,
    "partGrade": 0, --- This 0 should not be here
    "gachaConfig": 0, --- This 0 should not be here
    "amount": 3,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm... I must confess that I have no idea about the OP request! However, from the question title and the *"I am trying to only focus on building counters"* phrase, I assumed that the problem is related to *counters*...

I tryied at first to generate the same output above (the first time the OP indicated "My goal"), so I wrote this Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Count 0..5 and repeat
set "numbers=12"

set "serial=0"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numbers%) do (
   echo !serial!
   set /A "serial=(serial+1)%%6"
)
```

Then, I got an idea and dusted off my old "Merlin 256" model crystal ball (yes, the trusty 16-bit one) and asked it: "What is what the OP really wants?", and it answer: "A base-6 counter..."

Yes, of course! That makes a lot of sense, so I finally wrote this solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "numbers=25"

set /A "d3=d2=d1=0"
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numbers%) do (
   echo !d3!!d2!!d1!
   set /A "next=d1+1, d1=next%%6, C=next/6,  next=d2+C, d2=next%%6, C=next/6,  next=d3+C, d3=next%%6"
)
```

... and this is the output:

```
000
001
002
003
004
005
010
011
012
013
014
015
020
021
022
023
024
025
030
031
032
033
034
035
040
```

---

Ok, second round...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

del RESULTS_1.txt RESULTS_2.txt 2> NUL

set /A "d2=d1=0"

for /F %%a in (tester.txt) do (
   echo     %%a !d1!>> RESULTS_1.txt
   echo     %%a !d2!>> RESULTS_2.txt
   set /A "next=d1+1, d1=next%%6, C=next/6,  next=d2+C, d2=next%%6"
)
```

This is the input file **tester.txt**:

```
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
```

**RESULTS_1.txt:**

```
"code" 0
"code" 1
"code" 2
"code" 3
"code" 4
"code" 5
"code" 0
"code" 1
"code" 2
"code" 3
"code" 4
"code" 5
```

**RESULTS_2.txt:**

```
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 0
"code" 1
"code" 1
"code" 1
"code" 1
"code" 1
"code" 1
```

Comment: YES, YES, YES it works but question can you look at my questions and tell me if I added it correctly it seems to work but the section that does this `11111,22222,33333,44444,55555` it stops at five and that is because of `C` right so it I give a second code like  `D` /12  so it can do this 66666,77777,88888, that is what I would edit right